# can I use the phrase On the house in any place?

Tags: word-usage

Am I only allowed to use the phrase *on the house* in a bar or Can I use it in any other place? like if I' m working in a grocery store, and a old customer comes in and buy a bunch of stuffs , and I want to give him/her something for free, can I use the phrase *on the house*?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can even use it sarcastically: "This piece of advice is on the house"

Comment: Also possible "this one's on us"

Answer (score 2):

"*On the house*" does originate in the hospitality industry where bars and restaurants are termed "the house".

It is widely used outside this scope to refer to anything that is offered to a customer *without charge*. Even individuals, not businesses, may use the expression figuratively.

However, "on the house" is **not** the same as "free". It means that the house has waived the charge. In the context of a bar, it essentially means that the bar has bought your drink for you. A 'free' drink would be one that was *never going to be charged for*. So, if the grocery store is giving something away free, this isn't technically "on the house".

Also, you don't have to say something is on "the house". When an individual buys someone else a drink they might say "this one's on me". Likewise in any other setting, you can just say something you have bought for someone else when they expected to pay for it is "on me", or "on us". In my experience as a native BrEng speaker, I can't say I've ever heard a shop or store referred to as "the house", and it does sound a little odd.